# How to make a flexible playstore app Icon that supports both "Normal Mode" and "Dark Mode"

Tags: android

I have recently pushed a `React Native` app to playstore and used an `Icon` to represent in playstore.When **Dark Mode** is enabled my app's playstore `Icon's` background turns black which makes `Icon` ugly. Now my doubt is

1. Do I have to use white background for `Icon` for all the future apps?

OR

2. Is there any way to make our `Icon` to be flexible in both **Normal Mode** and **Dark Mode**?

Comment: do you mean your icon looks ugly once it is installed on the users screen or do you mean  it looks bad inside of playstore. I would use exactly the same Icon that users will see on their phones

Comment: @quealegriamasalegre My concern is only about playstore icon. It's not noticeable or clearly visible due to lack of white background in playstore when Dark mode is enabled. Do I need to add white background for playstore icons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regarding your first question if the issue is only inside of playstore I think light background will not hurt. I dont think google play store offers a way to make this adaptive on their website.

regarding the second one, yes! inside your android project you can place alternative versions of your launcher icon inside of `/res/mipmap-night-**` resource folder btw it is possible you will need to create it. And also I recommend you actually create `/res/mipmap-night-hdpi`, `/res/mipmap-night-xhdpi` etc. to take into account the different screen resolutions. Since you are developing with react you would have to dive into your android project to find the res folder, or alternatively open your project in android studio and you will see it right away.  this should change how your app looks on your users home screen

UPDATE
by mistake I had pointed to the `drawable-night-**` folders in my answer but Launcher icons in android are actually saved in the `mipmap` folders. I have now corrected this. I also tryed it out and it works (however I had to restart my device for it to take effect. asuming your users dont switch constantly between day and night mode they will always se the right icon for them)

Comment: I followed this and it kinda works, but not immediately: when switching the theme the icon won't update unless I restart the phone. Any idea why?

Comment: @Luca  yes I have observed this as well, I think it is related to your phones OS I am pretty sure it caches some of these icons and only resets them after some time or, as you said, after a reboot. I am not sure there is anything you can do about this

Answer (score 0):

Play Store icon it is a different image that you upload.
Make a complete white (or whatever) background to that image. In [the official guidelines](https://developer.android.com/distribute/google-play/resources/icon-design-specifications), Google says that you shouldn't make a partial background.

There is no "dark" icon in the Google Play Store; if you leave it transparent, it will display the default background color for each state (normal-dark).